# UISearchbar placeholder dislocated

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, placeholder

I have a `UISearchbar` in xib and the placeholder not located in perfect design.

See image[image]

Comment: u were add the uisearchbar in progrmatically or using tool method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITextField *txtField = [UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 20)];
    paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [txtField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [txtField setLeftView:paddingView];
    txtField.delegate = self;
    [txtField setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    txtField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```